# Set a UserControl property and change its value from Main Form

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I'm trying to change the value of a label in UserControl1 which is loaded in Form1.
I'm then trying to set the value of the label(UserControl) through a Main form textbox textchanged event.
The code I'm using in usercontrol is :

```
Public Property Testo() As String
        Get
            Return label1.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            label1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

and in the main form I'm doing:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim usercontrol1 As New UserControl1
    usercontrol1.testo = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

But I can't see the label changing its value.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: So you create a new instance of your usercontrol, but you don't appear to be adding to the form. Is that code elsewhere possibly? Did you possibly mean to be using an existing user control? Also, when you debug, does it go into 'testo' successfully?

Comment: Hi Andrew, My bad, I forgot to say that the control is load in form_load already, so I don't need to add it to form1. The problem endeed is the label not being filled with text at runtime.

Comment: 'Dim usercontrol1 As New UserControl1' <- but this will create a new instance of the control. So then you'll be interacting with this new control, and not the one on your form. If the one on your form has a fixed name, reference it by name, otherwise loop through the forms controls and find the control.

Comment: Oh yeah, In the beginning I was trying with a simple: usercontrol1.label1.text=textbox1.text thinking it was the problem, but Now I now. I just have to reference it by name once. Both codes are now working. Thanks Andrew! Appreciated